# Resolution in Zoom meeting app larger than desktop resolution

Tags: pantheon

The Zoom meeting app appears to be a larger resolution than the desktop. I've apt remove --purge, deleting any configuration files I could find using the find command, removing and reinstalling, installing from the deb file from Zoom, and installing from flathub. I had larger fonts set in the Settings of eOS and switched to the Default setting. The problems seems to have occurred after this, but I'm not 100% on that. I've attached a screenshot. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Did you see a helpful article in there? I couldn't find. Your sarcasm aside, I did search before posting. Maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing though.

Comment: I decided to provide a tutorial, because it has probably nothing with the settings inside zoom. It may probably solve your issue. Sorry, I am not even sarcastic. Maybe too much using Linux and most of solutions are too obvious for me. The first I always do is to use Google and YouTube and usually I can find an answer within 15 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For anyone else that might experience this, here's the answer I learned:

> I ended up creating a file at ~/.config/zoomus.conf:
>
> ```
> [General]
> autoScale=false
> ```

Comment: Strange I have set this value set as true and I do not experience issues with the resolution. So the question is what resolution are you using and what GPU do you have and what GPU firmware do you use. Maybe here is the explanation? Interesting solution. Worth to remember, but not something usual actually. Upvoted anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal to remove zoom. Type:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge zoom
```

Download the package for Ubuntu (64 bit, version 14.04+) from here: https://zoom.us/download?os=linux

Open terminal

type:

```
cd

cd Downloads

sudo apt install -y libglib2.0-0  libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-image0 libfontconfig1 libgl1-mesa-glx libxi6 libsm6 libxrender1 libpulse0 libxcomposite1 libxslt1.1 libsqlite3-0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-xtest0 libegl1-mesa libxcb-xtest0

sudo dpkg -i zoom_amd64.deb
```

Wait when it will finish installation without errors. It takes even up to 5 minutes.

I have a normal resolution after I installed it correctly.

[image: Zoom normal resolution]

Comment: Unfortunately, the obvious answer didn't help. I've done all of that before including manually searching my hard drive for any files related to Zoom. I did try your suggestion again to no avail.

Comment: Then I have totally no idea. Have no idea how Zoom is written by Microsoft. Even hard to say is it related to your GPU firmware or not. All I can say is reinstall the system and check on new system does the issue exist.